# Sequelize returns lowercase letter when inserting a one letter uppercase letter?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

How come sequelize inserts and returns a lowercase letter when I insert a one letter uppercase letter?

**Example**: I insert "N" and it saves "n" instead of "N".

I inserted it the following:

```
  console.log(toBeInserted) // let's say toBeInserted = "N" 
  db.dataset.findOrCreate({
    where:{
      name: toBeInserted
    }
  })
  .spread(function(inserted, created) {
    console.log(inserted); //here I get back inserted = "n"
  })
```

Looking at the SQL DB, I can see that `"n"` was stored and not `"N"`.

But once the input value consists of at least two letters, sequelize saves it correctly:

```
  console.log(toBeInserted) // toBeInserted = "Hi" 
  db.dataset.findOrCreate({
    where:{
      name: toBeInserted
    }
  })
  .spread(function(inserted, created) {
    console.log(inserted); //here I get back inserted = "Hi"
  })
```

In the DB, the value `"Hi"` was saved correctly.

Could anybody explain to me why that is happening and how I can prevent this? I want sequelize to save the values just like I inserted it, i.e. if I want to insert "N" (uppercase letter "N") it should save "N".

***Edit:***
Sequelize is able to save lowercase and uppercase one letter only inputs. However it seems like the method findOrCreate() isn't able to recognize uppercase from lowercase letter once you create it.

Example: I've got an empty database and I create the following input:

```
console.log(toBeInserted) // toBeInserted = "A" 
      db.dataset.findOrCreate({
        where:{
          name: toBeInserted
        }
      })
      .spread(function(inserted, created) {
        console.log(inserted + " " + created); //here I get back inserted = "A true"
      })
```

I check my DB, and indeed the are saved there with the correct upper/lower case.

After that I'll create the following data:

```
console.log(toBeInserted) // toBeInserted = "a" 
      db.dataset.findOrCreate({
        where:{
          name: toBeInserted
        }
      })
      .spread(function(inserted, created) {
        console.log(inserted + " " + created); //here I get back inserted = "a false"
      })
```

I check my DB again and the data hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't sequelize that is doing this.  I tested it and didn't reproduce the behavior you described.  Are you sure you're really sending "N" instead of "n" in the toBeInserted var?  Or maybe there is a trigger or something else in your db that causes this.

Comment: Nope. I tested it with different letters. Always the same outcome. It would save the standard letter instead the capital letter. But ok, I'll look further into that. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Short question: If you have already created an input, let's say "N" in your DB with sequelize and you want to create another one letter input with findOrCreate(), in this case "n". Does sequelize creates a new dataset "n" or returns the existing dataset "N"?

Comment: If I send "n" and it doesn't exist, it creates it.